# Choosing $101$ numbers from $\{1, 2, \dots , 200\}$.

Tags: number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I want to prove that if you choose $101$ numbers from the set $\{1,2,3,4,\dots ,200\}$, there are always two numbers such that one divides the other with no remainder. The proof should involve the "pigeonhole principle".

I am not sure how to define the pigeonholes and how to define the pigeons. Any assistance with the proof will be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Write numbers in form $2^kq$ where q is odd, then the result should follow easily

Comment: Do you mean like this: 1=(2^0)*1, 2=2*1, 3=(2^0)*3,...what are the holes and what are the pigeons? Not sure I am following you,

Comment: Well then the holes are odd number 1,3,5,..,199, then from 101 numbers there will be two with same q.

Comment: Got it, thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write each of the $101$ numbers as $2^kq$ for some odd $q$. There are $100$ choices for $q$. Hence there must be at least two of the $101$ numbers, $2^{k_1}p$ and $2^{k_2}p$, such that the odd number is the same and so one divides the other.

Comment: why there are 100 choices for q? I mean $101=101 \times 2^0$

Comment: Because $q$ is selected from odd divisors of numbers in $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, 200\}$, @LoveQYG.