# Explaining how the accepted solution works of a previous problem

Tags: proof-explanation, pigeonhole-principle

- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/769735/1021792 in the above stack post which was accepted as a answer , what will number $a_j - a_i$ indicates so as to solve the problem?

> What i get is that $a_1$ divides $a_j-a_i$ , but this doesnt tell me anything more . How to show there are two numbers that one evenly divides the other wih this approach .

- Note : i know the other proof of n boxes i would like to see how the accepted answer show us the proof of the claim . ( Also it should be $a_1 \leq 100$ not $99$)

Comment: Not only are you correct that $a_1\leq 100$ but I believe that there are only 100 remainders $r_2,\dots r_{101}$ (notice it starts from $r_2$) not 101!

Comment: Also as $a_1\leq 100$ the possible NONZERO remainders that may be obtained by division of $a_1$ are $1,\dots, 99$, that is in total, $99$.

Comment: The poster of that question did just ask for hints, but I'm with you - I don't see how that method leads to a final answer.

Comment: I see that was just hint , hmm understood . But yeah that hint doesnt gonna work much here

Comment: Yes I agree... Though I wonder how it got accepted, the hint does not lead anywhere it seems, the other answer should get accepted instead

Comment: I agree, the second answer makes a lot more sense. Here is a more elegant way of writing it down: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271176/choosing-101-numbers-from-1-2-dots-200?rq=1

Comment: That's beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah indeed , thank you @Andreas